# type use in using statment must be convertible to implicit System.Disposable

Tags: c#, using, idisposable, using-statement

I didn't understand the error. It seems to follow MSDN statement using.

```
               public void html() 
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest request = ((System.Net.WebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://url"));
            using (System.Net.WebResponse response = ((System.Net.WebResponse)request.GetResponse()))
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");


                using (System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encoding))
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(readStream.ReadToEnd());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException webEx)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Errore nella connessione - " + webEx.Message);
        }
    }
```

how to write a implicit Disposable ?

Comment: remove using statement from where you get that error. just write normal variable.

Answer (score 2):

[System.Net.WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) does not implement IDisposable, so you cannot have it in a using statement. A normal variable declaration should be ok.

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://url");

using (System.Net.WebResponse response = ((System.Net.WebResponse)request.GetResponse()))
using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
}
```

Comment: thanks man, but i read on MSDN [WebResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) that not implement IDisposable `public class HttpWebResponse : WebResponse, ISerializable`  why using run good for `using (System.Net.WebResponse response = ((System.Net.WebResponse)request.GetResponse()))` ???

Comment: @rul3z Because HttpWebResponse inherets from WebResponse. WebResponse then implements IDisposable.

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.WebRequest does not implement IDisposable. You need to remove the using() statement that wraps that varaible, and the error will go away.